# Swift codable dynamic keys for single entity

Tags: json, swift, codable

My JSON:

```
    "Filters": [
    { "filter": "View by",
      "products": [
        { "id": 1,
          "views": 56700
        },
        {"id": 2,
          "views": 60000
        }
      ]
    },
    { "filter": "Ordered by",
      "products": [
        { "id": 1,
          "orders": 5600
        },
        { "id": 2,
          "orders": 4300
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

As of now, the following structure is working for me, but not easy to use

```
struct Filter: Codable {
    let filter: String
    let products: [[String: Int]]
}
```

Is it possible to create a generic key structure only for some part of the product object?

In short, is it possible to apply generic structure only for "orders" and "views" and not for id?

For eg: Something like this

```
struct Filter: Codable {
    let filter: String
    let products: [Product]
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let _____: [String: Int] // Some unknown variable
}
```

Comment: Did you tried with any ??

Comment: Gives compiler error "does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Comment: where you fund the error i found both your exaple  code is working fine

Comment: Actually dynamic is not any key, Its just to show that as an example.

Comment: See now I have updated the code.

Comment: still not getting error . give you error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
protocol Product: Codable {
    var id: Int {get}
}
struct ProductByView: Product {
    let id: Int
    let views: Int
}
struct ProductByOrder: Product {
    let id: Int
    let orders: Int
}

struct Filter: Codable {
    let filter: String
    let products: [Product]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        //...
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //...
    }
}
```

But, implementing `Filter.init(from:)` or `Filter.encode(to:)` would be a little complicated.

In your case, you can work with this simplified workaround:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let views: Int?
    let orders: Int?
    //... you may need more?
}
struct Filter: Codable {
    let filter: String
    let products: [Product]
}
```